# remove xml tags with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml file:

```
<xfa:data>
  <form1>
    <Page1>
    <Page2>
    <contractInfo> ... </contractInfo>
    <paymentInfo> ... </paymentInfo>
  </form1>
  <commercialType> .... </commercialType>
  <userList> ... </userList>
  <officesList> ... </officesList>
  <commercialType> .... </commercialType>
  <userList> ... </userList>
  <officesList> ... </officesList>
  <commercialType> .... </commercialType>
  <userList> ... </userList>
  <officesList> ... </officesList>
</xfa:data>
```

I want to remove every ocurrence of the commercialType, userList and officesList nodes, so my output would be :

```
<xfa:data>
  <form1>
    <Page1>
    <Page2>
    <contractInfo> ... </contractInfo>
    <paymentInfo> ... </paymentInfo>
  </form1>
</xfa:data>
```

How could I do that using XSLT?

Thank you

Comment: Good Question (+1).

See my answer for a complete solution using and overriding the `identity rule`. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**This transformation produces the desired results**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="commercialType|userList|officesList"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Rohit, What is "it" and what "does not work"? Are you sure that you have the same source XML document as in this question? Are you sure that you execute the same transformation as the one in this answer? Are you sure you are using a compliant, non-buggy XSLT processor?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I do not have same xml or xslt but similar. I am using Visual Studio 2012. I found that using default namespace does not work. Thanks, works now.

Comment: I had an XML where the first node had a namespace (xmlns="...") but it wasn't a "default" namespace. This xslt didn't work. When I removed the namespace it worked. So try that if you have an Xml where it doesn't work.

Comment: @Rhyous,  'xmlns="..."' is declaration of a default namespace. xmlns:somePreffix = "..." is a declaration of non-default namespace. Your problem is a FAQ. Search for "default namespace and XPath" and you will find many good explanations. And yes, this answer will need to be modified in the case when namespaces are used in the source XML document. However, the current question doesn't have such source XML document. Therefore, once again, do read other questions and there are many on the topic of namespaces.

Comment: It leaves an empty line. How to get rid of that?

Comment: @zygimantus, Maybe this answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10712711/36305

Comment: Can you suggest how to keep the content inside removed tag (if it is a tag also)?

Comment: @zygimantus, Yes, you need to do searching or more systematic learning. Just have `<xsl:applu-templates/>` inside the matching template.

Answer (score -1):

Identity transformation plus `<xsl:template match="commercialType" priority="10"/>`.