# Camel xpath toLowerCase and contains

Tags: java, xpath, apache-camel

We are moving to camel in our application. I need to proccess some xml messages (get values\compare statuses). To solve this problems have bunch of custom processors written using pure java, but I was asked to change this using camel features.
Example of code:

```
.choice()
    .when().xpath("/Response/Header/Status = 'OK' ")......
```

This is working fine.

Now I need to compare hint with some other hint, to do this I need to set value of:

```
/Response/Header/Hint
```

to lower case and check for contains. 
If - /Response/Header/Hint value  (for example:

```
<Hint>MyHint</Hint>
```

- to lower case contains "hint" then route to... otherwise to ....
I am not xpath expert and camel looks like has some changes fo this, so can you please help me with this.

One more thing I am interested, how do I remove whole < Hint>MyHint< /Hint> before passing message forward (remove some tags)

And can you advice some tutorial to get quickly into xpath for camel.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `fn:lower-case(string)` to compare the hint as explained in [How can I convert a string to upper- or lower-case with XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586231/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-upper-or-lower-case-with-xslt).

About the removal of the `<Hint>` tag you have mutiple posibilities, like:

1. Use [XSLT](http://camel.apache.org/xslt.html) to filter the content as shown in [remove xml tags with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641681/remove-xml-tags-with-xslt)
2. Call a [Bean](http://camel.apache.org/bean.html) that does the filtering

Comment: Use XSLT to filter the content as shown in remove xml tags with XSLT. Worked perfectly! I have test failures probably some triming spaces are added\removed, but, I can see message is tranformed correctly, thanks! Will try now first

Comment: I need 15 reputation to accept, when have it, will accept!  thanks one more time!

Answer (score 1):

Answer is this:

```
.choice()
    .when().xpath("/Response/Header/Status/text() = 'OK'")
        .to("xslt:xsl/RemoveTag.xsl")
            .choice().when().xpath("//Response/Header/Hint[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'hint')]").to
```

RemoveTag.xsl is small changed [remove xml tags with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641681/remove-xml-tags-with-xslt)
Great thank to olivier roger!