# XSLT for removing tags

Tags: xml, database, xslt, tags, querying

How can we remove a tag or sub-element which is inside a tag. I have

```
<Catalog>
  <Department>
    <a1>...</a1>
    <a2>...</a2>
    <a3>
      <b3.1>...</b3.1>
      <b3.2>...</b3.2>
    </a3>
  </Department>
  <Department>
    <a1>...</a1>
    <a2>...</a2>
    <a3>
      <b3.1>...</b3.1>
      <b3.2>...</b3.2>
    </a3>
  </Department>
<Catalog>
```

And I want it to be

```
<Catalog>
  <Department>
    <a1>...</a1>
    <a2>...</a2>
  </Department>
  <Department>
    <a1>...</a1>
    <a2>...</a2>
  </Department>
<Catalog>
```

This is actually a question on the course the Stanford Online Learning, and I have tried a few things like

```
<xml:template match="a3" />
```

but it did not worked. So please help me as with this question, I will be able to have my Statement of Accomplishment.

Comment: Please go through this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641681/remove-xml-tags-with-xslt). Should solve your problem.

Comment: There are two ways to look at this: (1) copy only what you need; (2) copy everything, then exclude the things you don't need. The link in the comment above shows how to do (2).