# Removing elements from xml file with XLST

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt, soap

I'm attempting to remove certain elements from a soap response I get in XML format. However when I use the suggestions in the other XLST questions I always end up deleting all the content that is nested in the element. I just want to omit that part of the xml document so i can have a clean XML doc with no namespaces or soap envelopes etc.

I've attempted to use ideas like this: [remove xml tags with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641681/remove-XML-tags-with-xslt)

but with no luck. If somebody could help me achieve this it would be really great.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request_dataResponse encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><request_dataReturn type="soapenc:string"><Vessel>
  <VesselID>117774</VesselID>
  <IMO>7625988</IMO>
  <VslName>Shamrock Pride</VslName>
</Vessel>
</request_dataReturn></request_dataResponse>
```

Note that for some reason the vessel tag is not on the next line but is located at the end of the soap tags. There are also multiple soap tags called Request and Return in that one line.

What I wish to achieve is XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Vessel>
  <VesselID>117774</VesselID>
  <IMO>7625988</IMO>
  <VslName>Shamrock Pride</VslName>
</Vessel>
```

I have tried using XSLT as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="request_dataResponse|request_dataReturn"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it simply deletes all the data in the tags nested after the soap tags.

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: That's not really your input, is it? Because that's not a well-formed XML document: there are no closing tags for `request_dataResponse` and  `request_dataReturn` and `<Vessel>` does not match `</vessel>`. All you will ever get out of this is an error message.

Comment: Correct. I ommited part of the data due to it being company sensitive. But i assumed people would get the idea. correcting it now

Comment: The idea here is to run your code and reproduce the problem before moving on to solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am only guessing here, because your input is not an XML document, but to remove a wrapper element and keep its descendants you must do:

```
<xsl:template match="wrapper">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

That is, in your case:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="request_dataResponse | request_dataReturn">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What you have now processes the root `request_dataResponse` element and stops there.